# Read only permission to header files in XCode custom framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on my own custom framework creation in Xcode. I have created .framework successfully and included it in My Sample app. But when i look into my public header files (from .framework) in "MySampleApp", they are not read only. I want to make them read only files.

If we see any framework provided by Apple, all header files are locked. I want same kind of implementation.

I know it may be possible through script, but am not able to get success into. Have anyone done same kind of stuff?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused; you say static library and then mention framework. Which is it?

Comment: OK, so please correct your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this by using chmod command

```
 find "MyFramework/" -type f -name "*\.h" | xargs chmod 444
```

First I searched all .h files from .framework which get created in MyFramework folder and then changed permissions by chmod command.

Comment: Don't you want permission `0644` to allow **you** to overwrite the files during a build?

Comment: Yes you are right while developing we cant use 444...but while in releasing framework (Release mode) to client I can use 444.